# Accessing Database from FireMonkey app on MAC

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, macos-sierra, unixodbc

According to [Embarcadero's docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/UnixODBC_(FireDAC)), it is possible to setup `unixODBC` on a MAC and compile an app that connects to a database and run it on a MAC. The instruction shows how to compile the unixODBC but does not show how to create the required database drivers, which means no database connection can be setup. Has anyone been able to successfully do this?

FYI, I am trying to connect to a `Sybase ASE` database. I can create the 64 bit version of `unixODBC` and drivers using the instruction found [here](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/10454272) and use ***isql*** to run some queries against the database, but that is useless because applications created with RAD Studio are 32 bit (for MAC). and 32 bit apps cannot use 64 bit `unixODBC`.

Thank you
Sam